# Angular-locker Safari Private Browsing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari, local-storage, session-storage

We're using a third party wrapper around local/session storage called [Angular-locker](https://github.com/tymondesigns/angular-locker).

We need to be able to support Safari private browsing in our project but if the storage isn't supported, the browser just throws a JS exception and our angular app doesn't initialize. I've noticed the use of [Remy's Polyfill](https://gist.github.com/remy/350433) but is this just a plug and play script? How exactly am I supposed to use this in a project?

Currently we fallback to $cookies using **locker.isSupported()** but I don't understand the point of this function if I can't call or check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem similar to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/tmcgee123/c25325d70277b2ee3f3a).

The solution was to just override some of the decorator functions using [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory), if the driver was not able to be intialized. We just switched using [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) to [$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) instead.